# Cannot flash Esp32 C3 SuperMini (Revision 0.4)

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32, espressif-idf

**I am not able to flash esp32c3 super mini. here are outputs of arduino and esptool**

```
Serial port COM4
Connecting...
Chip is ESP32-C3 (revision v0.4)
Features: WiFi, BLE
Crystal is 40MHz
MAC: dc:da:0c:8e:aa:d4
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Changing baud rate to 921600
Changed.
Configuring flash size...
Flash will be erased from 0x00000000 to 0x00003fff...
Flash will be erased from 0x00008000 to 0x00008fff...
Flash will be erased from 0x0000e000 to 0x0000ffff...
Flash will be erased from 0x00010000 to 0x00047fff...
Compressed 13200 bytes to 9522...

A fatal error occurred: Packet content transfer stopped (received 8 bytes)
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 2
```

Esp tool also not able to detect flash size

---

```
esptool.py v4.5.1
Found 2 serial ports
Serial port COM9
Connecting...
Detecting chip type... ESP32-C3
Chip is ESP32-C3 (revision v0.4)
Features: WiFi, BLE
Crystal is 40MHz
MAC: dc:da:0c:8e:a0:bc
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Manufacturer: 3f
Device: ffff
Detected flash size: Unknown
Hard resetting via RTS pin...
```

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kq0h.png)

Comment: so after more research i found that there are 2 version 1 with flash memory and 1 without supplier send me a chip without flash memory one so i changed esp32 module from local market and its working now